# Javascript OOP counting value doesn't work outside class

Tags: javascript, function, variables, counting

I have this count variable. Each time I press a certrain button the count variable counts one and it starts with 0 as a default. This works, but when I try using it outside the class it doesn't remember the value. I know this shouldn't work, but I have no idea how to do it right

```
    class navigation{

        constructor() {
            this.count = 0;
        }

        NextBtn(){
            this.count++
            console.log(this.count);
        }

        ResultBtn(){
            console.log(this.count)
        }
    }
```

I want the value to be available everywhere like here:

```
 let nav = new navigation();
 const count = nav.count;
 btn.addEventListener("click", function (btn) {
     nav.NextBtn();
     console.log(count)
})
```

But out of there logs I get the default value which is 0. How do I do this right?

Comment: Well, you are creating a new instance of `navigation` with `count=0` on every button click.

Comment: You are creating a new `navigation` object every time the button is clicked. You need to create the object outside of the click handler

Comment: Also: your class name should really be capitalised (`Navigation`), and its methods should be camel case (eg. `nextBtn`). It's a general naming standard in JS.

Comment: @UnholySheep I created the object outside the handler, but it still logs 0 each time

Comment: @TLausie - That's because you never call `NextBtn`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried calling NextBtn() But now everytime I click anywhere it counts 1 and inside the handler it still stays 0

Comment: @TLausie - Why did you move `const count = nav.count;` out of the click handler? You're (now) grabbing it as it is right at the start. (That *copies* the value -- `0` -- from `nav.count` into `count`, there's no ongoing relationship between the `count` constant and the `nav.count` property.) You want it **after** it's been changed. Just move that bit back inside the handler.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Got it! the problem is that if i put NextBtn in the handler it counts one everytime I press btn (btn is different than nextbtn) so the count gets all messed up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are instantiating a new navigation every time you click, you want to move that outside:

```js
class navigation{

    constructor() {
        this.count = 0;
    }

    NextBtn(){
        this.count++
        console.log(this.count);
    }

    ResultBtn(){
        console.log(this.count)
    }
}

const next = document.getElementById("next");
const result = document.getElementById("result");

const nav = new navigation();

next.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    nav.NextBtn();
})

result.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    nav.ResultBtn();
})
```

```html
    <button id="next">Next</button>
    <button id="result">Result</button>
```

EDIT: Added a second button to show how to add independent listeners

Comment: In an event handler, the parameter passed is the event, not the element

Comment: You're right, i just copy pasted that part, i'll fix it

Comment: The problem is that NextBtn and btn are not the same, It should only count when next is pressed which is why I didn't put NextBtn in the handler

Comment: You can define a different listener for each button, i edited the code, hope this is cleared now

Comment: I know how to add an independent listener, but if I do that I can't use the count variable inside the other one.

Comment: You can if you define the nav outside the listeners, have you seen my updated example? you can execute it right here and see the result

Answer (score 0):

If you want `count` to be a public property on each `Navigation` instance, then you need to refer to it correctly from outside the object instance, using `nav.count`.

Note how, in the following, each `Navigation` instance maintains its own `count` public instance variable.

```js
class Navigation {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0
  }

  count = 0

  next() {
    this.count++
    console.log("From inside `next`: ", this.count)
  }
}

let nav1 = new Navigation()
let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1")

let nav2 = new Navigation()
let btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2")

btn1.addEventListener("click", function (btn) {
  nav1.next()
  console.log("From inside btn1 event listener: ", nav1.count)
})

btn2.addEventListener("click", function (btn) {
  nav2.next()
  console.log("From inside btn2 event listener: ", nav2.count)
})
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Click me 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Click me 2</button>
```

Alternatively, if you create a block-scoped variable outside the class, it will be shared by the code in the current block.

Note how, in the following, the block-scoped variable `count` is shared by every instance of `Navigation` we create.

```js
let count = 0

class Navigation {
  next() {
    count++
    console.log("From inside `next`: ", count)
  }
}

let nav1 = new Navigation()
let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1")

let nav2 = new Navigation()
let btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2")

btn1.addEventListener("click", function () {
  nav1.next()
  console.log("From inside btn1 event listener: ", count)
})

btn2.addEventListener("click", function () {
  nav2.next()
  console.log("From inside btn2 event listener: ", count)
})
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Click me 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Click me 2</button>
```